# Javascript causing inifinite loading on mobile only

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a website that is still pretty simple.
You can click on ingredients and it shows you possible meals you could make with the selected ingredients.
While the site is working as intended on PC (tested on two different PCs), the page is loading infinitely on mobile (tested on android: chrome and firefox).
If I exclude my app.js file, the site is loading normally, so I guess the problem is somewhere in there.

The code is rather long (over 250 lines) so I don't know how I should upload it.

I googled my problem but found nothing so far, would be great if anybody could help.

Comment: Do you want us to review 250 lines of code to find out something you, the writer of the code, couldn't?

Comment: Please read [ask]. You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question and explain the problem more specifically. Show us what you've tried in debugging the problem including and error messages you receive.

Comment: Mobile browsers have the option to attach to the debugger remotely from your pc. Try looking into that for the page and show your results.

Comment: @lilezek To be honest I was hoping the problem is something fundamental in my code, like the scope of my functions or something similar, since I am not really familiar with mobile browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem:

I was able to find the problem after some additional debugging.
There was a problem in the calculation of the element's locations in js.
If the width of my parent div falls below a specific value, the script is rounding down to 0 and is trying to divide by 0 in the next line.

I am still confused because usually js is responding with an error to division by 0, but at least it works now..